# Java error when trying to install pip for python3

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, pip, java-15

I am struggling to download pip for python3. I am working on macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.7).
I use the following command line :  `sudo apt install python3-pip`
In the beginning, I had no JDK and did download one from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html. Now that I have Java SE 15.0.2, I encounter the following problem when trying to install pip :

`Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)`

I did check and the "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" does not exist.

However, "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/" does.

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If you just need python or pip installed and do not care about JVM i would recommend brew to install.
Brew is an alternative package manager designed specifically for macOS.
You can install brew from here: https://brew.sh/

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer !
I do have brew, in fact, I want to install Keras and tensorflow, Brew does not seem to have Keras, it is why I use pip..

Comment: To install python (including pip) i can recommend this page: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python .
There you can find more information about installing python and pip using brew.